# Are $\{re^{i\theta}: 0<r\le 1, 0\le \theta < 2\pi \}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times (0,1]$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Are $A := \{re^{i\theta}: 0<r\le 1, 0\le \theta < 2\pi \}$ and $B:=\mathbb{R} \times (0,1]$ homeomorphic?

My intuition tells me no. And yet, I can not find a single topological property that one has and the other doesn't.

Comment: $A$ is a closed unit disk with its center deleted, right? If so, I think it fails to be simply connected while $B$ is.

Comment: I think you are right, yet I haven't formally learned what "simply connected" means. Is there a different way to show they are not holmeomorphic?

Comment: @DavidZhang: $A$ is not compact (the origin is missing)

Comment: @DavidZhang: $A$ is not compact - its closure contains the center of the disk.

Comment: Oh, of course! Don't know what I was thinking there.

Comment: @amirbd89: Do you know what homotopy is? And do you accept that $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not homeomorphic? If so, you can note that $A$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ and $B$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @john: No, unfortunately I don't know what homotopy is, at least not formally. :(

Comment: @SimonS: Why does it matter what happens to $A$ and $B$ in the ambient space? how does it effect homeomorphism?

Comment: @SimonS: Yes, I share the same misunderstanding of your reasoning. If instead $A = (0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $B = \mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, then $\overline{A} = [0,1]$ is compact, $\overline{B} = B$ is not compact, but $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: Apologies, you're right. Deleted.

Comment: @SimonS: No problem.

Comment: @amirbd89: What topological tools have you learned so far that could be used to solve this problem? Not knowing about homotopy is unfortunate.

Comment: @john I know, compactness, local compectness, first countable, second countable, connectedness, path-connectedness, local connectedness, local path-connectedness, $T_0, ... , T_4$.  I should say that it is possible that this question is not practically solveable without homotopy. I just wondered whether I miss something I can do with my tools.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @amirbd89: I believe these tools may be sufficient for the answer I have posted, which I hope does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given (from the comments) that using homotopy will not be helpful for the asker, here is a solution that avoids it. I assume as understood that $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not homeomorphic. This is clear since the former is compact and the latter is not. I also assume as understood that $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism between a subspace $U$ of $A$ and the image $f(U) \subset B$ with the subspace topology. A reference for this fact is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808677/topology-homeomorphism-with-restricted-domain).

Suppose, for sake of contradiction, there exists a homeomorphism $f : A \rightarrow B$. Denote by $U$ the set of points $x$ in $A$ such that there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ for which $V\setminus \{x\}$ is homeomorphic to the punctured half-disk $D := \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert (a,b) \rvert < 1, (a,b) \not= (0,0) \mbox{ and } a \leq 0\}$. The homeomorphism $f$ *must* send $U$ to the analogously defined subset in $B$ (otherwise it does not restrict to a homeomorphism on $V\setminus \{x\}$), and vice versa for $f^{-1}$. Hence $f$ should restrict to a homeomorphism $f\rvert_U : U\rightarrow f(U) \subset B$ (with $U$ and $f(U)$ endowed with the subspace topologies) between these specific sets. However, $U \cong \mathbb{S}^1$ whereas $f(U)\cong \mathbb{R}$. This is a contradiction.

Hence $A \not\cong B$.

Comment: How do you know the punctured half-disk is not homeomorphic to the open punctured disk? This isn't very much simpler than the original problem.